# $(1/r, 1/r)$ satisfying set system contains $r$ pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, set-theory, computer-science

I am quite confused why $Pr(\mathcal E_i)>0$ means $\mathcal F$ contains an $i$-monochromatic set in the end of proof of lemma 1.6 of [Improved bounds for the sunflower lemma](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.08483.pdf). Don't we need $Pr(\mathcal E_i)=1$ to guarantee this?

Thanks in advance for explanation!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an analogy: if a person is drawn randomly from the collection of all citizens of the world, what is the probability that they are a contributor on math.stackexchange? Having this probability be larger than $0$ is equivalent to the statement, "There exist MSE contributors," and having the probability be equal to $1$  is equivalent to, "Everyone in the world is an MSE contributor."

Comment: I understand now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help! Please consider accepting the answer so that the question can be marked as closed in the MSE system.